# How to get fetch api results in execution order with async/await?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise, async-await

After an input change in my input element, I run an empty string check(`if (debouncedSearchInput === "")`) to determine whether I fetch one api or the other.

The main problem is the correct promise returned faster than the other one, resulting incorrect data on render.

```
    //In my react useEffect hook
        useEffect(() => {
           //when input empty case
           if (debouncedSearchInput === "") autoFetch();
           //search
           else searchvalueFetch();
        }, [debouncedSearchInput]);
```

searchvalueFetch() returned slower than autoFetch() when I emptied the input. I get the delayed searchvalueFetch() data instead of the correct autoFetch() data.

What are the ways to tackle this? How do I queue returns from a promises?

I read [Reactjs and redux - How to prevent excessive api calls from a live-search component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47238596/reactjs-and-redux-how-to-prevent-excessive-api-calls-from-a-live-search-compon) but

1) The promise parts are confusing for me

2) I think I don't have to use a class

3) I would like to learn more async/await

Edit: added `searchvalueFetch`, `autoFetch`, `fetcharticles` code

```
  const autoFetch = () => {
    const url = A_URL
    fetchArticles(url);
  };
  const searchNYT = () => {
    const url = A_DIFFERENT_URL_ACCORDING_TO_INPUT
    fetchArticles(url);
  };
  const fetchArticles = async url => {
    try{
      const response = await fetch(url);
      const data = await response.json();
      //set my state
    }catch(e){...}
  }
```

Comment: the code you posted doesn't seem to use promises or fetch - please show the code that you are having an issue with

Comment: I just added more

Answer (score 0):

This is an idea how it could looks like. You can use promises to reach this. First `autoFetch` will be called and then `searchvalueFetch`:

```
   useEffect(() => {
     const fetchData = async () => {
       await autoFetch();
       await searchvalueFetch();
     };

     fetchData();

   }, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a function in any lifecycle depends on your project.

```
lifecycle(){
     const fetchData = async () => {
try{
       await autoFetch();
       await searchvalueFetch();
} catch(e){
console.log(e)
}
     };

     fetchData();

   }
}
```